# How to print the Views title in page.tpl.php?

Tags: views, 7

I could print the view with this code in `page.tpl.php`.

```
print $view->display['view_display_name']->display_options['title'];
```

How can I print the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) title ?

Answer (score 0):

You can aptly use this function [views_embed_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/views_embed_view/7). This will help you to print out the view, passing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you are actually looking for how to define `$view`. That can easily be done with [`views_get_view()`](http://%60https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view/7.x-3.x). Add `<?php $view=views_get_view('YOUR-VIEW'); ?>` to `page.tpl.php` or predefine the variable with [`template_preprocess_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x) in your theme's `template.php` file. You can then print the View's title with your code line.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your template.php

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $name = 'view_machine_name';
  $display_id = 'block_1';
  $view = views_get_view($name);
  if(isset($view) && !empty($view)) {
    $head_title = $view->get_title();
    $variables['view_title'] = $head_title;
  }
}
```

add the following variable anywhere in the page.tpl.php file used by your theme.

```
 print $view_title;
```